# Force initialization to 0 when inserting into a std::map

Tags: c++, c++11, stdmap, allocator, size-t

I have a `std::map<std::string,std::size_t>` of keys mapping counters. When I increment a counter, I don't know if it already exists. If yes, it is incremented. If not, it is set to 1. This is easy to do:

```
std::map<std::string,std::size_t> counters;
//...
auto c_it = counters.find(key);
if(c_it == counters.end())
  counters.insert(key,1);
else
  (*c_it)++;
```

This is a lot of code for a simple thing... I want to do this:

```
counters[key]++;
```

But this generates undefined behavior because `std::size_t()` is called when the counter doesn't exist in the map, and there is no guarantee that `std::size_t()` initializes to 0.

I see two potential solutions:

1. Find / create a type similar to `std::size_t` forcing initialization to 0 when created with default constructor. Is there such a type in `std` or `boost` ?
2. Find / create a dedicated allocator to replace the default `std::allocator<std::pair<const Key,T>>` given as 4th template argument of `std::map`. But I have no idea how to do it.

Note: I use C++11 only (I don't want solutions for C++>=14)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But this generates undefined behavior because `std::size_t()` is called when the counter doesn't exist in the map, and there is no guarantee that `std::size_t()` initializes to 0.

This assumption is incorrect. Quote from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at):

> If an insertion is performed, the mapped value is [value-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) (default-constructed for class types, zero-initialized otherwise) and a reference to it is returned.

<sub>The quote is for pre-C++11 version, but it's easier to understand that the tuple magics and the observable effect is the same.</sub>

The value will be zero-initialized, you can use `counters[key]++;` without issues.

Answer (score 5):

`++counters[key];` is completely valid. `std::map::operator[]` inserts a value-initialized element if the key does not exist in the map. This is the idiomatic way of doing what you explained.